# Problem rendering Custom "MenuItem"

Tags: c#, wpf, render, menuitem

Here's my problem:

when i open my program in my computer the option menu is rendered like this:
http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/1623/prob1.jpg

but when i open my program with my **father**'s computer and my **brother** computer the MenuItem renders out like this:
http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/3451/prob2l.jpg

as you can see in my computer it renders the text in black and in others computer renders the text in white.

Here's my code:

```
<Separator>
    <Separator.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border CornerRadius="2" Padding="5" Background="PaleGoldenrod" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Global Options (Are Saved):" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Separator.Template>
</Separator>
```

Comment: it's not necessary to add "[C# / WPF]" to your title. We've got tags for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the texblock foreground to Black? (Perhaps Vista / 7 has Black as default while XP does not, forcing it to be black might help)

```
<TextBlock Text="Global Options (Are Saved):" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" />
```

Comment: Oo, it worked. thanks for the simple solution. how didn't i think about it? :(

Comment: Glad it helped, and it happens! I always go blind when looking at my own code for too long! ;)